# How to make element active in sidebar which is in django include tag through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, include

I have made sidebar in sidebar.html
and had include it in main.html as well as dashboard.html through django include tag to reduce data reduntancy->

```
         {% include 'employee/sidebar.html' %}

         {% block content %}
 
         {% endblock %}
```

Now how do I make different elements (in sidebar) active according to the different pages?
Like for example, When I am on dashboard.html , dashboard should be active in sidebar.

Here is sidebar.html

```
  <ul>

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="admin_dashboard.html">
        <span>Dashboard</span></a>
   </li>


    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="main.html">
        <span>Create</span></a>
   </li>


 </ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `employee/sidebar.html`? One way you could do this is to compare the current path from `request.path` with the path for the nav item

Comment: <ul>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="admin_dashboard.html">
            <span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="main.html">
            <span>Create</span></a>
    </li>
  

</ul>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag for getting the path to your other views/urls, this tag takes an argument `as` that stores the result of the tag as a variable, this variable can be used to add classes if the current path matches the URL

```
<ul>
  {% url 'dashboard' as dashboard_url %}
  <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == dashboard_url %}active{% endif %}">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ dashboard_url }}"><span>Dashboard</span></a>
  </li>
  {% url 'main' as main_url %}
  <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == main_url %}active{% endif %}">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ main_url }}"><span>Create</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```